# How can I catch a NullPointerException from a method? Example inside

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, mapquest

I am using the MapQuest jar in my Android app and I just came upon an issue with one of the methods required by the RouteManager.RouteCallback() that is a part of the MapQuest jar.

The method giving me the NullPointerException is the onError() method, as you will see in the code below. How can I catch a NullPointerException from that method so the app will not crash? I've tried wrapping the entire method in a try/catch but that doesn't work, it is giving me errors. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
routeManager.setRouteCallback(new RouteManager.RouteCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onError(RouteResponse routeResponse) {
            Info info = routeResponse.info;
            int statusCode = info.statusCode;

            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message.append("Unable to create route.\n").append("Error: ")
                    .append(statusCode).append("\n").append("Message: ")
                    .append(info.messages);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            createRouteButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(RouteResponse routeResponse) {
            clearButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (showItineraryButton.getVisibility() == View.GONE
                    && showMapButton.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                showItineraryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            createRouteButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

    });
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:230)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.mapquest.android.maps.RouteManager.handleResponse(RouteManager.java:393)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.mapquest.android.maps.RouteManager.access$400(RouteManager.java:59)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.mapquest.android.maps.RouteManager$RouteTask.onPostExecute(RouteManager.java:648)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.mapquest.android.maps.RouteManager$RouteTask.onPostExecute(RouteManager.java:611)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-11 14:26:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you wrap it?

Comment: What error do you get when wrapping the entire inside of the function with try/catch?

Comment: Can you paste to a pastebin the nullpointerexception as well?

Comment: Why not check the variable that might be null, if it is null?

Comment: Could you provide stack trace of the NullPointerException?

Comment: Stack Trace: http://pastebin.com/nfH80uRT

Comment: The NPE is "println: needs a message" and is happening is some code I don't have access to. Nothing within the onError method itself is causing the NPE. It happens immediately after exiting the onError method

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It is giving me a bunch of build errors.

Comment: @nmjohn I don't get an error when I wrap the inside of the function, but that is not what is causing the NPE. It is happening immediately after it exits the onError method. Nothing within the onError method is causing the NPE.

Comment: What is at routeManager.java line 393? curious

Comment: If you comment out all the code in these functions, do the results change? Is NPE thrown?

Comment: @beta0x64 I have no idea, that is a class that is part of the MapQuest jar being included in my apps build path.

Comment: @beta0x64 I've tried that, and Yes, I still get the NPE. So it is something outside of these functions. At first I thought it was something with the onError method, but obviously not. When debugging, I get the NPE immediately after I exit the onError() method

Answer (score 0):

You don't catch `NullPointerException`. You simply don't do anything with `null` references.

Check which reference is `null` exactly, and check `if (foo != null) {..}`

Comment: NullPointerExceptions can be catched, even though it may not be a good idea in most applications.

Comment: in 99% of the applications. I didn't say it's not possible. I said you don't do it that way.

Comment: The NPE is "println: needs a message" and is happening is some code I don't have access to. Nothing within the onError method itself is causing the NPE. It happens immediately after exiting the onError method.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to catch NullPointerException. You should avoid dereferencing a null variable. For example checking that the variable is not null if you think it might be.

In your example it looks like `createRouteButton` is null for some reason.

Comment: I didn't include the entire Activity, createRouteButton is defined in other code and is not null. The NPE is "println: needs a message" and is happening is some code I don't have access to. Nothing within the onError method itself is causing the NPE. It happens immediately after exiting the onError method

Comment: If that's the case, it doesn't have anything to do with this code. Stacktrace?

Comment: Stack Trace: pastebin.com/nfH80uRT

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we must admit defeat. You can either attempt to break open the jar with a sledgehammer or hang your head and post a thread at MapQuest's forums.

:(

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/forums/-/message_boards?_19_mbCategoryId=224714

Edit: Oh, it's worth a shot. Are you using the latest build of MPQ API?

Comment: I do have the most recent version. I am actually trying to edit to source file that is causing the issue now. We'll see how it goes.